# How to prevent parent click event when dragging from child to parent

Tags: javascript, preventdefault, dom-events, stoppropagation

If you want a click inside a child element not to bubble to its parent you can stop the bubbling using `stopPropagation`

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>

document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', ()=> { .. }
document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('click', ()=> { .. }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xxrnLu2w/2/)

But how do you prevent the parent click, when the click begins inside the child and ends outside. In other words: `mousedown` inside the child, then a `mousemove`, which moves the pointer outside the child (but inside the parent) and then `mouseup`

The most important thing for me, is that in this situation I don't want the parent click, any suggestions ?

UPDATE: If you remember the mousedown target, you can use this in the parent click callback: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xxrnLu2w/3/). But I hope there is a better solution

Comment: Note behavior is different in firefox than chrome. Parent click does not trigger in firefox when mouseup occurs

Comment: I was testing in Chrome :) But FF shows the behaviour I need!!

Comment: Right...I figured that. I was confused at first since I first checked demo in firefox and seemed fine there

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping that I understand your question clear enough.  You are looking for an event or some type of method that would allow you to always find the first value clicked. e.stopPropagation() & the capture property as the third parameter for an event listener will not work either.

What I would do in the mean time would be to add an additional variable outside of your listeners scope.  onClick you can assign that variable to which ever item you click on.

or you can modify your click handlers to be ['mousedown.'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousedown)   That way it is irrelevant if the user drags away from the part they first click.  The second the user mouses down, they will trigger the event.